# AsyncTask, Thread or Services to run long shell command

Tags: android, multithreading, shell, android-asynctask, threadpool

In my current project , I have to run 5 differents binaries and show the output in different textView , those binaries give continuous output and will be run for a long time ( let's say 3/4h min ) therefore  what is the best way to implement those ?

AsyncTask are easier but there will be some problem, if the user jump let it run in the background, so I guess I will have to go for Thread or Services?

The question is which one should I use ? and if you have any advices on how to implement it ( or maybe a library ? ) I am taking any help ...
Thanks a lot for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntentService  or  ExecutorThreadPool

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Well it is exactly my question ... Which one is the best/easier/stick to my need ?